# SQL Query Not Filtering Results as Expected - Excluding Results with Certain Column Value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am attempting to write a SQL query that filters a table based on presence of a certain column value in a joined table.

I have a table `pull_requests`, a join table `pull_requests_releases`, and a table `releases`.

The `pull_requests_releases` table joins `pull_requests` to `releases` on `pull_requests.id = pull_requests_releases.pull_request_id` and `pull_requests_releases.release_id = releases.id`. Fairly straightforward.

I am attempting to gather all `pull_requests` for which their `releases` subset does NOT include a certain value in the `releases.app_id` column.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT pull_requests.* from pull_requests 
  INNER JOIN pull_requests_releases ON pull_requests.id = pull_requests_releases.pull_request_id 
  INNER JOIN releases ON pull_requests_releases.release_id = releases.id
```

This gets all `pull_requests` that have at least one linked `release`. This step is fine. Next is where I'm unsure of what to do. I need to filter these results further to only include the `pull_requests` for which a specific value does not exist in their `releases` subset.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT pull_requests.* from pull_requests 
  INNER JOIN pull_requests_releases ON pull_requests.id = pull_requests_releases.pull_request_id 
  INNER JOIN releases ON pull_requests_releases.release_id = releases.id
  WHERE [number] NOT IN (SELECT releases.app_id)
```

but **all this does is get rid of the `releases` with that `app_id` first, and then still returns the `pull_requests` with the other `releases`.**

I also tried `having` as such:

```
SELECT pull_requests.* from pull_requests 
  INNER JOIN pull_requests_releases ON pull_requests.id = pull_requests_releases.pull_request_id 
  INNER JOIN releases ON pull_requests_releases.release_id = releases.id
  GROUP BY pull_requests.id, pull_requests_releases.id, releases_id, releases.app_id
  HAVING [number] NOT IN (SELECT releases.app_id)
```

and I'm seeing the same results.

I need to do the filtering at the *end*, per se - leave the `releases` alone, and filter the `pull_requests` at the end whose `releases` contain that value. Almost like placing a filter on results at the end of the query. Is this possible?

I'm testing with a `pull_request` linked to two `releases`, one with `app_id` 1 and one with `app_id` 2. I attempt with [number] as 2 and expect the query to check the `pull_request`'s `releases`, see that there exists a `release` with `app_id` of 2, and accordingly NOT return that `pull_request`. However, what is happening is the `pull_request` is still being returned, just with one linked `release` instead of two.

Sorry if my explanation is poor. Thanks.

Comment: I think you just have to say someting like WHERE releases.app_id <> 1234 that should filter the rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM pull_requests p -- you only want to select from pull_requests
WHERE NOT EXISTS (   -- except when some release exists
        SELECT *
        FROM releases r 
        JOIN pull_requests_releases pr ON pr.release_id = r.id
        WHERE p.id = pr.pull_request_id
        AND r.app_id NOT in (12345,6789)
        )
        ;
```

---

Your question already had the query hidden in it:

> I am attempting to gather all pull_requests for which their releases subset does NOT include a certain value in the releases.app_id column.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `NOT IN` format might be incorrect:

> The `pull_requests_releases` table joins `pull_requests` to releases on
>   `pull_requests.id = pull_requests_releases.pull_request_id` and
>   `pull_requests_releases.release_id = releases.id`. Fairly
>   straightforward.
>
> I am attempting to gather all `pull_requests` for which their releases
>   subset does NOT include a certain value in the `releases.app_id` column.

```
SELECT pr.*
FROM pull_requests pr
JOIN pull_requests_releases prr
  ON pr.id = prr.pull_request_id
JOIN releases r
  ON prr.release_id = r.id
WHERE r.app_id NOT IN (<list_of_values>);
```